# scala c integration

Tags: c, scala, sbt

I would like to port some of my scala code to c and call this ported code from my current project. But I did not find any documentation about how to do that. It would be great if this would be possible just from sbt, because thats my current build system.

Currently I have heared about SNA, but without documentation

I am not looking for an automatic scala to c compiler or anything like that. I just don't know how to write the interface between scala and c

Comment: so you want to call scala code from c or c code from scala?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, I think I answered your question. Two other people did too, but you did not mark any of these to be an answer. That's strange.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I doubt that you will find a sbt-only solution for compiling C code.  Even if you found an sbt plugin that did compile C code, I would be really surprised if it did it well.  Compiling native libraries is just too different compared to compiling Scala.

For compiling your C or C++ library, I recommend [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) or [Automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/).  Neither is perfect, but both do a good job of allowing you to basically declare "compile these .c or .cpp files into a .so".  Automake is more popular with open source projects, but CMake is quite a bit simpler.  CMake also has good support for compiling on Windows, if that's a requirement.

For accessing your native library from Scala, I recommend using [JNA](http://jna.java.net/).  It allows you to access native code from any JVM language, including Scala.  And it does so without the glue layer or code generation required by [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

I've ported [the JNA example](http://jna.java.net/#getting_started) from Java to Scala.  There are a couple of things to note.

1. Java varargs are different from Scala varargs.  If you want to call a variadic C function, you'll have to write the interface in Java instead of Scala.  But you will use that interface exactly like you would if it were written in Scala.

   - I wanted the example to remain strictly in Scala, so I used `puts` instead of `printf` in the example
2. I did pretty much a straight port.  You may want to make things a bit for Scala-esque.

And the code:

```
import com.sun.jna.{Library, Native, Platform}

trait CLibrary extends Library {
  def puts(s: String)
}

object CLibrary {
  def Instance = Native.loadLibrary(
    if (Platform.isWindows) "msvcrt" else "c",
    classOf[CLibrary]).asInstanceOf[CLibrary]
}

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    CLibrary.Instance.puts("Hello, World");
    for ((arg, i) <- args.zipWithIndex) {
      CLibrary.Instance.puts(
        "Argument %d: %s".format(i.asInstanceOf[AnyRef], arg))
    }
  }
}
```

As an aside, it's funny that you mention specifically not wanting a Scala to C compiler.  There was a [recent paper](https://days2011.scala-lang.org/sites/days2011/files/ws3-2-scalallvm.pdf) published about compiling Scala to LLVM, which would have largely the same effect as a Scala to C compiler.

Comment: I am accepting your answer as the correct one. But I am not quite happy about the solution. I was hoping to have something that integrates nicer with the way how a java/java application are shipped. The compilation for the different targets bunding them and then loading the correct version on application startup is what I was hoping to get some automation. I think SBT and CMake are two horribly complicated beasts that bite each other.

Answer (score 13):

Scala and C are fundamentally different programming languages. You cannot expect to have an automatic converter from Scala to C.

If you want to call Scala code from C code or vice-versa, you should use the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). In this case, you will have a running JVM executing your Scala code, and that JVM will load your C code as a dynamic native library and allow it to interact with your Java/Scala code through JNI. It's not easy or straightforward though; you have to read and try out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As far that i know there is in the moment no way to export scala code to C. But you are free to write that by yourself ;)

Comment: I know there is a project to run scala on LLVM. This could be a posibility for the future...